# When is (a+b+c)(1/a+1/b+1/c) integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I was a kind of curious over this for past few days,

If $a_1, a_2, a_3$ can be any natural nos, what are the distinct integer values $(a_1+a_2+a_3)(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3})$ can attain. Or even if we cannot determine what are these integer values, can we determine wether there are finite or infinitely many of them . My initial thought was also to extend to this to n terms rather than just 3 , but considering n=2 is easily dealt with and for n=3 I am unable to solve, I would like a solution to that first.

Thanks

Comment: btw if a3=a2a1 A version of that is asked in hmmt[a math contest]

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, I found the duplicate using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(a%2Bb%2Bc)(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bc%7D)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1).